# Help with speaker installation

Tags: chevrolet, audio, cavalier, speakers

I have a 2004 Chevy cavalier coupe, also bought speakers for the back. Now in order for me to put the rear speakers in I basically need to take the rear end apart. If you can help me step by step on how to do so that would be great but other wise I was thinking about keeping the already existing ones and somehow adding the two new ones to it. How would I do that?

Comment: I would have to argue that it is not too broad to put it simply: its a 2004 cavalier coupe. A straightforward question about how to get the rear deck interior panel off. Followed by a how do I add 2 more speakers to the rear left and right lines. It isn't written very well but I don't think it is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you only need to take the rear deck out (hard cloth thing behind and above the seats under the rear window that has the speaker grates in it). Then 4 screws each and they come out.

right that might help ... watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWF-T7VI8ME)

Comment: Any reference to "*looks like*"? What are you looking at? Is it something the OP can view on the Internet?